# Expo managed iOS build is failing for unknown reason

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an expo managed app that I have trying to build for iOS using `eas build -p ios`. However, it is now failing to build (despite successful builds previously). The error on expo appears as

```
Build failed: The "Run fastlane" step failed with an unknown error. Refer to "Xcode Logs" below for additional, more detailed logs.
```

Upon further inspection of the logs, a snippet of the fastlane logs:

```
› Compiling react-native-maps Pods/react-native-google-maps » AIRGoogleMapPolylineManager.m


❌  (node_modules/react-native-maps/ios/AirGoogleMaps/AIRGoogleMapPolylineManager.m:17:9)

  15 | #import <React/RCTViewManager.h>
  16 | #import <React/UIView+React.h>
> 17 | #import "RCTConvert+AirMap.h"
     |         ^ 'RCTConvert+AirMap.h' file not found
  18 | #import "AIRGoogleMapPolyline.h"
  19 | 
  20 | @interface AIRGoogleMapPolylineManager()

› Compiling react-native-maps Pods/react-native-google-maps » AIRGoogleMapPolyline.m

    Run script build phase '[CP-User] Generate app.config for prebuilt Constants.manifest' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'EXConstants' from project 'Pods')

    Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-Codegen' from project 'Pods')

    Run script build phase '[CP-User] Generate app.manifest for expo-updates' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'EXUpdates' from project 'Pods')

    Run script build phase 'Start Packager' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Harlyy' from project 'Harlyy')

    Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Harlyy' from project 'Harlyy')

    Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')

▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **

▸ The following build commands failed:

▸   CompileC /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/react-native-google-maps.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AIRGoogleMapPolylineManager.o /Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-maps/ios/AirGoogleMaps/AIRGoogleMapPolylineManager.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'react-native-google-maps' from project 'Pods')

▸ (1 failure)

** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

and the Xcode logs:

```
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -target arm64-apple-ios13.0 -fmessage-length\=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit\=0 -std\=gnu11 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path\=/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval\=86400 -fmodules-prune-after\=345600 -fbuild-session-file\=/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror\=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -fmodule-name\=react_native_google_maps -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror\=return-type -Wdocumentation -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror\=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Werror\=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_RELEASE\=1 -DCOCOAPODS\=1 -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS\=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES\=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS16.2.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -Wunguarded-availability -iquote /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/react-native-google-maps.build/react_native_google_maps-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/react-native-google-maps.build/react_native_google_maps-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/react-native-google-maps.build/react_native_google_maps-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -ivfsoverlay /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/react-native-google-maps.build/all-product-headers.yaml -iquote /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/react-native-google-maps.build/react_native_google_maps-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/react-native-google-maps/include -I/Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Pods/Headers/Public -I/Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-callinvoker -I/Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-runtimeexecutor -I/Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/hermes-engine -I/Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Pods/Google-Maps-iOS-Utils/src/Heatmap -I/Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Pods/Headers/Public -I/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/react-native-google-maps.build/DerivedSources-normal/arm64 -I/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/react-native-google-maps.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -I/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/react-native-google-maps.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/react-native-google-maps -F/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/DoubleConversion -F/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Google-Maps-iOS-Utils -F/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/RCT-Folly -F/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-Core -F/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-cxxreact -F/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-hermes -F/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-jsi -F/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-jsiexecutor -F/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-jsinspector -F/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-logger -F/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-perflogger -F/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Yoga -F/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/fmt -F/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/glog -F/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libevent -F/Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Pods/GoogleMaps/Base/Frameworks -F/Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks -F/Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal -F/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/hermes-engine/Pre-built -DHAVE_GOOGLE_MAPS\=1 -DHAVE_GOOGLE_MAPS_UTILS\=1 -fno-modules -include /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/react-native-google-maps/react-native-google-maps-prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/react-native-google-maps.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AIRGoogleMapPolyline.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/react-native-google-maps.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AIRGoogleMapPolyline.dia -c /Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-maps/ios/AirGoogleMaps/AIRGoogleMapPolyline.m -o /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Harlyy-gduxmkxrnmmmlgcaawnqeyxcsxmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Harlyy/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/react-native-google-maps.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AIRGoogleMapPolyline.o

​

warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] Generate app.config for prebuilt Constants.manifest' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'EXConstants' from project 'Pods')

warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-Codegen' from project 'Pods')

warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] Generate app.manifest for expo-updates' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'EXUpdates' from project 'Pods')

warning: Run script build phase 'Start Packager' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Harlyy' from project 'Harlyy')

warning: Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Harlyy' from project 'Harlyy')

warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
```

Obviously, it appears to be something to do with this 'react-native-maps' package. But I wouldn't know how to go about fixing this.

I have also attempted a build after resetting the cache, via the expo console.